# Laravel Nested views with logic

Tags: mysql, laravel, view, nested

please I need help as I can't figure out what the best approach to my problem is.

I will try to make the long story short:

I have an application which has many subapplications laveraging from the same code and is entirely database driven. Lets imagine that you have a record which doesn't use the typical horizontal database approach but rather vertical, meaning 1 record with 40 fields doesn't have 1 row with 40 columns in database but 40 rows which have the same "record id" and each row represents a different field where each row's other columns specify other atributes of that field like order,section or field id and **field type**.

When I say field type I don't mean just regular field types like checkbox,radio,text etc. but there are also **custom fields** which have complex logic.

now, each field type has it's own template(view) which is included in a loop when the whole record is created on the view. So when I want to update a record updadeEditController takes the record based on the record id from the database which will grab those e.g. 40 fields meaning 40 rows and sends it to the updateEdit view. In this view it is looping through those 40 rows and calls/includes views for each field type.

```
@foreach ($fields as $field)
  @if($field->intSectionId == $section->id)
     @include('field.edit.' . $field->strFieldType
  @endif
@endforeach
```

as I mentioned some of these fields have some complex logic including queries etc which should run and render data on each field's view and I don't want to put logic in each field type view in blade which is considered a bad practice and it should be.(but it would really help in this scenario :) )

my question is what is the best approach to bind a logic to each subview which is generated dynamically based on field set. As I mentioned at the beginning this application has many subapplications which are basically using the same code and the number of applications may grow and also field sets may be changed for each subapplication going further so it is important for me to keep each fields logic somewhere else than in the controller itself, but rather have the logic for each field view somehow tied to those views.

thanks.

Comment: This is too much to read. Try using bullet points and explain your question in a manner which is agnostic from your application.

Comment: "a record which doesn't use the typical horizontal database approach but rather vertical, meaning 1 record with 40 fields doesn't have 1 row with 40 columns in database but 40 rows which have the same "record id" and each row represents a different field where each row's other columns specify other atributes of that field like order,section or field id and field type." this sounds like the database needs to be normalized, and is likely the root of your need for complex logic. Consider revisiting how you have modeled the data.